# Magnetic field, Vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions, gauge

I have a question about the vector potential $\textbf A$ of a magentic field $\textbf B$, we know that  $$\nabla\times  \textbf A=\textbf B$$  and that  $$\nabla ^2  \textbf A = -\mu _0 \textbf j. $$  In my book it says that the solution for an infinite, homogenous space is given by: $$A(\textbf r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\textbf j(\textbf r')d^3\textbf r'}{|\textbf r - \textbf r'|} $$ and to get this solution you need to assume that it's radially symmetric and that for $|\textbf r |\rightarrow \infty$ , $A(\textbf r) \rightarrow 0 $ and use the Green's function approach.

**How do I know if I can use this formula to get the solution?**

Let's say I've got a rotating uniformly charged spinning ball, I know that $\textbf B$ is perpendicular to $\textbf r$ at any point, but since $$\textbf B  = \nabla \times \textbf A$$ that doesn't tell me much about $\textbf A$, whether or not it's radially symmetric or does it ? If this was the Electric potential this would be easier, because I know that the $\textbf E(\textbf r)$ points "radially out" and is dependend only on $|\textbf r|$, and the solution of $$\nabla^2 U = -\rho / \epsilon _0$$ should be radially symmetric... I can just imagine the ball consisting of small point charges, each of which gives a radially symmetric solution, and then I just "sum up all the contributions".

**What is the analogy for $\textbf B $ and $\textbf A$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you asked the first question because the assumptions that lead to the formula for $A(r)$ tell you when you can use the formula.I will interpret the second question as you asking for a more transparent relationship between $B$ and $A$ i.e one that allows one to have a concrete picture in mind.

Start with $B = \nabla\times A $ and then integrate over a closed surface $ \Sigma $ to get a flux integral $\int B \cdot d\Sigma = \int (\nabla \times A) \cdot d\Sigma = \int A \cdot dl $. Therefore we have $ \int B \cdot d \Sigma = \int A \cdot dl $. Using this equation, you can picture the magnetic potential as wrapping around the magnetic flux.